# Laravel Cashier (Stripe) - Checkout - invoice.paid & invoice.payment_failed events (webhooks)

Tags: laravel, laravel-cashier, stripe-payments

When using Checkout Subscriptions, the Stripe documentation states that the minimum event types to monitor are:

- `checkout.session.completed` - When you receive a checkout.session.completed event, you can provision the subscription.
- `invoice.paid` - Sent each billing interval when a payment succeeds.
- `invoice.payment_failed` -Sent each billing interval if there is an issue with your customer’s payment method.

> When you receive a checkout.session.completed event, you can provision the subscription. Continue to provision each month (if billing monthly) as you receive invoice.paid events. If you receive an invoice.payment_failed event, notify your customer and send them to the customer portal to update their payment method.

https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/checkout#provision-and-monitor

However, I am still confused about `invoice.paid` and `invoice.payment_failed` events and Laravel Cashier:

Do I need to make handlers for these two events?
I'm asking this because Cashier already handles `customer.subscription.updated` and `customer.subscription.deleted` events and, if I understood well (correct me if I'm wrong):

- if the payment (for renewal of the subscription) is successful next month, then I will receive `customer.subscription.updated` and the subscription will continue being `'active'`: `$user->subscribed('default')` will be `true` (in `subscriptions` table `stripe_status` will remain `active`).
- However, if the payment fails next month (for example, due to insufficient funds) - then `customer.subscription.updated` event will be triggered/sent and Cashier will change the subscription's status (to `canceled` or `incomplete`?) and `$user->subscribed('default')` will be `false`, right?

If so, then I see no reason why I should make handlers for `invoice.paid` and `invoice.payment_failed` events. I will know if the payment (renewal of the subscription) was successful because `customer.subscription.updated` event will be triggered/sent and Cashier will update the`stripe_status` in `subscriptions` table.

Or I'm wrong and it won’t work that way? If I didn't understand well, then I guess that `customer.subscription.updated` event will not be triggered/sent at all, or it will but it will not contain information if the payment (renewal of the subscription) was successful or not (and if it failed, then in handler method for the `invoice.payment_failed` event I will have to update the `stripe_status` (in `subscriptions` table) to `canceled` or `incomplete`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether the subscription gets deleted or not after a failed invoice payment is up to your subscription settings: https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/billing/automatic

As such it's possible to get a `invoice.payment_failed` event and not have the subscription be cancelled.

Since those events are very different it's safest to listen to all of them and handle accordingly. `customer.subscription.updated` and `invoice.paid` are also very different, the former will fire whenever any update to the subscription is made (e.g. if you update the metadata) whereas the latter will only fire specifically when an invoice payment succeeds.

It's ultimately up to you, but to ensure that you don't miss any important events you should consider listening to all the aforementioned events.

Comment: Thanks. One question regarding Laravel Cashier which already has handler for `customer.subscription.updated` event: If the payment fails next month (for example, due to insufficient funds) - then `customer.subscription.updated` event will be triggered/sent and *Cashier* will update the subscription's status (`stripe_status` column in `subscriptions` table) and then `$user->subscribed('default')` will be false, right? If so, then in handler method for `invoice.payment_failed` event I don't need to update anything in `subscriptions` table, I can just use it to "know" if payment failed or not?